# Extracting subgraph from neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, subgraph

I have a graph in neo4j database.  I want to extract a sub graph given a particular node  and a particular depth.
I tried using the traversal framework, but it only returns a set of paths.  It gives path up to a particular depth. 
 How can i construct a sub graph based on the set of paths that i get?  Is there any other way to get the required result?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "subgraph"? A list of nodes (and their relationships)?

Which language/framework do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that, by subgraph, you mean a list of nodes, and you've got the Path objects from the traversal already, you could just collect the end nodes of each path in a list.